# Calculate affine transformation from bounding box coordinates

Tags: raster, affine-transformation, world-file

How do you calculate the geo-affine transform given the bounding box coordinates and image size. For instance, I have the coordinates as follows:

```
Top-Left: -108.01575, 45.01846
Bottom-Left: -108.00717, 44.01024
Top-Right: -106.79887, 45.01751
Bottom-Right: -106.81054, 44.0093
```

Image Size is 5960x7040

From this information, how do I calculate the six values for the geo-affine in a world file?
Note that the bounding box is not a perfect square, so there will be some skew.

Comment: Could you share with us which software you are using?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/465993/edit) to add this info.

Comment: @GforGIS. I am not using a third party GIS api or software. I am looking for how to mathematically calculate the affine parameters. The affine will be used later to reproject the image using projNet and SkiaSharp.